# After implementing package reference model, code is getting build in visual studio 2019 but not using standard ms build command

Tags: msbuild

I am in process of setting CI CD pipeline, my project is build on top of one product, so i have dependencies on that product's dll.
Previously we were palcing all the dll in project solution on GIT.
Now, we have implemented Nuget package reference model, by migrating from package config and keeping all the third parties dlls on Nexus.

My project gets build in visual studio, but when i try to build from command prompt using msbuild it gives CS0246 the type or namespace could not be found, I have resotred nuget package using nuget restore command and packages downloaded successfully on package folder, the also getting error

Answer (score 0):

Use msbuild integrated restore when compiling, so make sure all calls to `msbuild.exe` include a `-restore` option:

```
msbuild.exe -restore -target:Build the.sln
```